# Enable syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to add some language hints for syntax highlighting to a post, but they don't appear to work. [According to @JeremyBanks](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5812915#5812915), syntax highlighting is not enabled on this site.

On Stack Overflow, these work as expected:

> [image: screenshot of the editor and preview on Stack Overflow]

Here on DevOps, they don't work:

> [image: screenshot of the editor and preview on DevOps]

I expect code snippets to be common enough in posts here (e.g. shell scripts), so please enable Prettify for the site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is now enabled, but off by default - you'll need to use [the language hints](https://devops.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to trigger it.

Eventually, it may make sense to set up default languages for specific tags, but much too early to determine that now.

Comment: Would you mind adding a relevant link to "language hints", which contains some explanation about where and how to do so?

Comment: Done http://devops.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting